# Does objective-c have an online playground like the one Go has?

Tags: objective-c, go

Wanted to know if  there were any online compilers/playground for objective-c like

[Go language online compiler](http://golang.org/doc/play/)

*Since Google-ing didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [ideone](http://ideone.com/) briefly, when I was playing around with Ada for assignment work, it has a compiler for Objective-C as well.